# jquery wont fire the event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">

  function buttonClicked(e)
  {

    alert(e.data.color);  
  }

 jQuery('#but1').bind('click',{color:'red'},buttonClicked);
  jQuery('#but2').bind('click',{color:'blue'},buttonClicked);
</script>
</head>



<body>

<br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <div align="center">
    <form action="" method="get">

    <input id="but1" type="button"  value="Red" />
    <input id="but2" type="button" value="Blue" />
    </form>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

The alert doesnt get triggered on the click..why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
function buttonClicked(e) {
    alert(e.data.color);  
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#but1').bind('click',{color:'red'},buttonClicked);
    jQuery('#but2').bind('click',{color:'blue'},buttonClicked);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RTXxY/

Comment: Because the elements you're selecting aren't available yet if the click handlers are set in the markup before the elements fall. As the page is parsed, elements become available to the DOM; `$(document).ready()` waits until the page is fully parsed and ready.

Comment: Check out the documentation for the `ready()` function: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

You have the script placed above where the elements are defined so when the code executes, there's nothing to bind to. The easiest solution is to only execute the script when the document is ready.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#but1').bind('click',{color:'red'},buttonClicked);
    $('#but2').bind('click',{color:'blue'},buttonClicked);
}
```